# Angular ng-pattern causes binding to break

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a form:

```
<div class="panel-group">
    <label for="url" tooltip="Enter the Engine as a Web Service (EWS) URL the Empower Editor will use for PDF preview.">EWS URL</label>
    <input id="url" size="50" ng-model="config.ewsUrl" required ><br/>
    <label for="PreviewTimeout" tooltip="Specify how long the Empower Editor will wait for a response from the PDF preview.">Preview timeout (Seconds)</label>
    <input id="PreviewTimeout" type="number" min="15" max="60" required ng-model="config.previewTimeout" style="width: 150px;">
</div>
```

When I add an ng-pattern attribute to the input it breaks the binding:

```
<div class="panel-group">
    <label for="url" tooltip="Enter the Engine as a Web Service (EWS) URL the Empower Editor will use for PDF preview.">EWS URL</label>
    <input ng-pattern="/^((ht|f)tp(s?)\\:\\/\\/)?[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.\\?\\,\\:\\'\\/\\\\\\+=&amp;%\\$#_]*)?$/" id="url" type="url" size="50" ng-model="config.ewsUrl" required><br/>
    <label for="PreviewTimeout" tooltip="Specify how long the Empower Editor will wait for a response from the PDF preview.">Preview timeout (Seconds)</label>
    <input id="PreviewTimeout" type="number" min="15" max="60" required ng-model="config.previewTimeout" style="width: 150px;">
</div>
```

If I remove the reg ex, it goes back to binding again.  What could cause this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because your regex is invalid. Why do you have all those double backslashes? You only use those when you create a new `RegExp` object. You're using the literal notation (`/stuff/`). If you move the regex to the controller and remove the backslashes, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/y7v9P/ . In addition, if you just fix the regex in the attribute, it seems to work too: http://jsfiddle.net/Mg9EH/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to validate a url. You don't need to use a regular expression or the `ng-pattern` option for this. Instead just use the following:

```
<input type="url" id="url" type="url" size="50" ng-model="config.ewsUrl" required/>
```

That in mind, the real reason that you aren't getting model binding is probably because the regular expression is not validating the values entered (either because it is incorrect or it is not a valid regular expression). I put together a quick plunker demonstrating what happens with valid and invalid values (on a validated field).

**[See the plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/2H8fj429ARhBvih8xr3L?p=preview)**.

**EDIT - Version Using ng-pattern**

If older browser support is important, you will probably still need to also use `ng-pattern`. In order to do this you need to make sure the regular expression is in the correct format (leading and trailing slash, but no "g"). For an example I pulled a regular expression for url's [from here](http://regexr.com/37i6s) and implemented it in the following code:

```
  <input id="url" type="url" size="50" ng-model="config.workingUrl2"
    ng-pattern="/https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/"
    required/>
```

**[See this working in the updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2H8fj429ARhBvih8xr3L?p=preview)!** Best of luck!

Comment: Does this work in browsers that don't support `type="url"`? I don't think so. I think that's the point of the `ng-pattern` specifically

Comment: @Ian Good point. This will work in IE10 and newer, and all other "modern" browsers except Safari per [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs.html). I'll update my answer with a working pattern for the chance that older browser support is important.